# JBoss Arquillian: Spring MVC Integration

Tags: spring-mvc, jboss-arquillian

I am just trying to integrate one of my existing Spring MVC application with Arquillian integration test. So far no luck.

**My application structure**

**Core Module**, **Web Module** and **Test Module**. I am trying to test my **Core Module** which is Spring Hibernate data layer. Test module contains all the test cases. Web Module depends on the core module and test module. Test module depends on the core module.

I am generating .war using maven. The .war contains the core module as well as test module in WEB-INF/lib as dependency. I am using embedded tomcat 7.

But while running the test case I am getting the below exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 1 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:605)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:509)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1437)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1019)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:503)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:338)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
... 26 more
```

**My aquillian.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<arquillian xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian 
http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
<container qualifier="tomcat" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="tomcatHome">target/tomcat-embedded-7</property>
        <property name="workDir">work</property>
        <property name="bindHttpPort">8888</property>
        <property name="unpackArchive">true</property>
        <property name="serverName">arquillian-tomcat-embedded-7</property>
    </configuration>
</container>
 <extension qualifier="spring-deployer">
    <property name="autoPackage">false</property>
</extension>
</arquillian>
```

**My pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>myApp-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>myApp-test</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>myApp-test</name>
<description>This is a test module of entire ear</description>

<properties>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.2.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.7.12</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>

<!-- Arquillian CORE Dependencies -->
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.11.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Project module dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>myApp-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson JSON Processor -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSR 303 with Hibernate Validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Arquillian Unit Testing Container (JUNIT) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Arquillian Suite Extension -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eu.ingwar.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-suite-extension</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-service-deployer-spring-3</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Beta3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-service-integration-spring-inject</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Alpha1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.34</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <!-- Tomcat Embedded -->
    <profile>
        <id>arquillian-tomcat-embedded</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-tomcat-embedded-7</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.CR5</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- org.apache.tomcat -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.42</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.42</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.42</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
                <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
                <version>3.7</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Weld for Dependency Injection @Inject -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.9.Final</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
                <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-service-deployer-spring-3</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Beta3</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-service-integration-spring-inject</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.Alpha1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-transaction-spring</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.Alpha1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-transaction-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

**My Suite Deployment class**

```
import java.io.File;

import org.eu.ingwar.tools.arquillian.extension.suite.annotations.ArquillianSuiteDeployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ArchivePaths;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.EmptyAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;

@ArquillianSuiteDeployment
public class SuiteDeployer {

private static final String warFilePath = "../myApp-web/target/myApp-web-1.0.war";

@Deployment(name="normal")
public static WebArchive deployBuild() {
    WebArchive webArchive = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Deploying WAR...");
        File warFile = new File(warFilePath);
        webArchive =  ShrinkWrap.createFromZipFile(WebArchive.class, warFile)
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, ArchivePaths.create("applicationContext.xml"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return webArchive;
}
}
```

**My Test case**

```
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.OperateOnDeployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class LaunchArquillian {

@Test
@OperateOnDeployment("normal")
public void testGetMessage() {
    ExplorerServiceImpl explorerServiceImpl = new ExplorerServiceImpl();
    Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 25);
    explorerServiceImpl.getConnAllDetails (pageable, "CREATION_DT", "ASC", null, false);
}
}
```

Expert please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Any update on this? I am badly looking for a solution of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. OK. You got a WAR and you want to deploy it to ARQ to run some tests. But usually, and I think that's the case also, you want a test root context to be a bit different than a production / normal one. Same apply for a persistence.

So you may want to clone the WAR and replace context.xml and persistence.xml config files with the test ones, buuuut without actually changing their names or paths.:

```
    // remove original context, replace with test context
    webArchive.delete("/WEB-INF/spring/test-context.xml");
    webArchive.add(new ClassLoaderAsset("test-context.xml"), "/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml");

    // remove original persistence (useless now), add test persistence config
    webArchive.delete("/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml");
    webArchive.add(new ClassLoaderAsset("META-INF/persistence-test.xml"), "/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence-test.xml");
```